# About ChIPpeakAnno and makeVennDiagrams

Tags: r, venn-diagram

I am using the function vennDiagrams from the ChIPpeakAnno library and I get a strange error message...

```
venn=makeVennDiagram(RangedDataList (anna, Anna_TSS),NameOfPeaks = c("peaks","TSS"),maxgap = 100, totalTest = 1000)
Warning message:
In findOverlappingPeaks(Peaks[[1]], Peaks[[2]], NameOfPeaks1 = NameOfPeaks[1],  :
Please use select instead of multiple!
```

I guess the findOverlappingPeaks function is running in the background of the venndiagrams but how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can safely ignore the warning message. Alternatively, you can download the newest version. Also, you might be interested in reading [this article](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/bioconductor/2010-November/036540.html) (for setting an appropriate totalTest).

Comment: You should add your email in your profile instead of inside an answer.